# How do I tell which one of two paths is a Symbolic Link?

Tags: symlink

I have a Macbook Air.  I followed [this tutorial](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/services-and-opening-sublime-from-the-terminal/) to set up a shortcut to open Sublime from my terminal.

If I understand symbolic links correctly, the original path is like a paved road that takes you to the corner store.  It is official and provided by the government, and as a result usually involves getting in a car and going far out of your way to get where you want to go.   A symbolic link is like the shortcut you take through the woods to get there faster.  It's a dirt path and you make it yourself.  However, it lets you go directly there.

Now I am curious. I ran the file command on both the original path and the symbolic link I created using the tutorial. I got the following results.

```
Taras-MacBook-Air:Desktop tlroys$ file /Users/tlroys/bin/subl 
/Users/tlroys/bin/subl: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Users/tlroys/bin/subl (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Users/tlroys/bin/subl (for architecture i386): Mach-O executable i386

Taras-MacBook-Air:Desktop tlroys$ file /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
```

So...they look exactly the same to me.  How do I tell which one is the symbolic link?

Answer (score 0):

`file -h /Users/tlroys/bin/subl` - the `-h` flag tells `file` to look at the symlink itself, rather than following it and looking at the result.

Source: http://ss64.com/osx/file.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command ls to list the details of the files in a directory or a specific file.

```
ls -l
```

The -l will be long format. For instance:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/subl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  64 Oct 29 23:04 /usr/bin/subl -> /Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

The -> indicates a symbolic link and shows what it points to.

If you do the same on the actual file, you will not see the ->:

```
ls -l /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 jennapederson  admin  160688 Jun 26 23:27 /Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```